# <input type="date"> no es reconocido en internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html

He intentado colocar

`<input type="date" name="fechaesperada">`

Pero no me reconoce el control internet explorer 11 
Alguno sabe que debo instalar o con que sintaxis debe estar para tener un control para manejar un calendario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El único navegador que acepta la sintaxis de HTML5 por completo es Google Chrome y Microsoft Edge de resto deberías probar la función  datepicker de jquery es muy buena... https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

[Internet explorer no soporta input[date]](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime/embed/). El unico navegador de microsoft que lo soporta es `Edge`. Tendras que utilizar [datetimepicker de bootstrap](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) si quieres tener un calendario en tu aplicacion.

Answer (score 0):

Varias de las características nuevas de HTML 5 no están soportadas por múltiples navegadores o versiones de estos, IE11 no soporta el input date es por eso que no funciona.

Puedes checarlo [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Y puedes checar [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) los demás input y los navegadores que lo soportan.